# Need help with XSLT 1.0 and grouping

Tags: c#, xslt, grouping

I have the following XML file:

```
<Promotions>
  <Promotion>
    <Category>Arts &amp; Entertainment</Category>
    <Client>Client Five</Client>
    <Title>Get your Free 2</Title>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <Category>Arts &amp; Entertainment</Category>
    <Client>Client 5</Client>
    <Title>Get your Free 4</Title>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <Category>Arts &amp; Entertainment</Category>
    <Client>Client five</Client>
    <Title>Get your Free 5</Title>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <Category>Community &amp; Neighborhood</Category>
    <Client>Client 1</Client>
    <Title>Get your Free 1</Title>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <Category>Education</Category>
    <Client>Client 3</Client>
    <Title>Get Your Free 3</Title>
  </Promotion>
```

I would like to group by category. I tried the following and keep getting errors:

```
string  xslmarkup = @"
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
  <xsl:output method='html' />

  <xsl:key name='Categories' match='Promotions/Promotion' use='Category'/>

  <xsl:template match='/'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select='
      /Promotions/Promotion[
        generate-id() 
        = 
        generate-id(key ('Categories',Category)[1])
      ]
    '/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='Promotion'>
    <xsl:value-of select='Title'/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
"
```

I would like something like this as the output:

```
    <h1>Arts &amp; Entertainment</h1>
    <ul>Client Five</ul>
    <ul>Get your Free 2</ul>

    <ul>Client 5</ul> 
    <ul>Get your Free 4</ul> 

    <ul>Client five</ul> 
    <ul>Get your Free 5</ul> 

    <h1>Community &amp; Neighborhood</h1> 
    <ul>Client 1</ul> 
    <ul>Get your Free 1</ul>

    <h1>Education</h1> 
    <ul>Client 3</ul> 
    <ul>Get Your Free 3</ul>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you do \*not\* want output like the sample you show. Your output sample lacks any kind of structure, all that's left is node order. This is quite a bad use of XML, and you should stay clear of it. Also: What is the error you receive?

Comment: It isn't exactly what I want I just need to group them into an unordered list grouped by category.

Comment: error: InnerException = {"'Categories' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 9, position 85."}

Comment: this is the line that is causing the error:

 <xsl:apply-templates select=' 
      /Promotions/Promotion[ 
        generate-id()  
        =  
        generate-id(key ('Categories',Category)[1]) 
      ] 
    '/>

Comment: @Vecdid: I just wanted to make sure that this is the error you receive (because I already thought so). You have incorrectly nested single quotes in your XSLT string (easily spotted: just count opening and closing single quotes on the line that throws the error). You need to fix them first.

Comment: @tomalak all that open are closed

Comment: @Vecdid: And *still* they are incorrectly nested. ;-) I did not say that you miss a closing one.

Comment: The text of the XSLT is wrapped in double quotes, inside the template match of the root node you use single quotes to begin the select statement for the apply-templates, but then use single quotes again when you generate-id and use the key(which is terminating the @select prematurely). Externalize your XSLT into a file, or find a way to escape the quotes for the string variable.

Comment: Can you take a look at the line and tell me what is wrong with the syntax then?

Comment: @Vecdid: This is what I wanted you to find out yourself (because it is more a string building issue than an an XSLT problem): "find a way to escape the quotes" - should not be that hard, actually.

Comment: When I put it in an external file and changing all the single quptes to double quotes except for the 'Categories' from the line above I get a different error :

ex = {"Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment. "}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error is your quoting but the logic appears flawed too. This isn't a pretty solution but it should get you on the right track.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:key name="categories" match="Category" use="." />
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="/Promotions/Promotion/Category[
        generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('categories', .)[1])
      ]">
      <xsl:variable name="cname" select="." />
      <Category title="{.}">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Promotions/Promotion[Category=$cname]">
          <Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="Title" />
          </Title>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Category>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you this:

```
<Category title="Arts &amp; Entertainment">
  <Title>Get your Free 2</Title>
  <Title>Get your Free 4</Title>
  <Title>Get your Free 5</Title>
</Category>
<Category title="Community &amp; Neighborhood">
  <Title>Get your Free 1</Title>
</Category>
<Category title="Education">
  <Title>Get Your Free 3</Title>
</Category>
```

Comment: @gum411: Indent code blocks by four spaces (select text and press CTRL-K, or use the "010101" editor button). Edit your post to see what I mean.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Note that the `<xsl:for-each select="/Promotions/Promotion[Category=$cname]">` is equivalent to `<xsl:for-each select="key('Category', .)">`.

Comment: @gum how can I change this XSLT to output :
<Category>Arts &amp; Entertainment</Category>
instead of
<Category title="Arts &amp; Entertainment">

Comment: remove title="{.}" from the Category tag and use <Category><xsl:value-of select="."/></Category> instead.